# Como utilizar uma função Python no Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Atualmente estou com um problema em que não encontrei nenhuma solução que eu tenha conseguido compreender e executá-la. Estarei resumindo aqui o escopo do que eu necessito, pois senão ficaria muito extenso.

Em um trabalho, fiz algumas funções em Python que envolvem processamento de imagens em Python, em que eu utilizo bibliotecas como OpenCV e Pytesseract, para ter uma ideia melhor sobre o assunto, pode consultar uma dúvida minha aqui no Stack sobre o assunto, conforme:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61599703/detecting-warm-colors-in-the-python-image

A função que eu criei basicamente recebe um diretório que contêm imagens ou uma imagem isolada (em .jpg), faz os processos necessários e retorna a imagem com as indicações de localização de ponto quente (conforme a imagem abaixo) e a temperatura neste ponto (um número float).

[image: Resultado da função de ponto quente]

Obs: O círculo em azul, Coodinate e Value são resultados da função e não fazem parte da imagem original.

Com isto, eu gostaria de criar um aplicativo Web que aplique essas funções, utilizando Django, por já ter essa interação com o Python. Minha ideia é criar uma página que eu possa entrar com as imagens que eu desejo analisar, através de um forms (esta parte já está pronta, consigo entrar com as imagens através do  [Uploading multiple files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files) e salvá-las no banco de dados).

Em outra página, gostaria de colocar um botão que execute esta função nas imagens salvas anteriormente e salve os resultados (imagem .jpg e o valor float) no banco de dados, para que eu possa mostrá-los no template para visualização do usuário. É esta parte que não estou conseguindo evoluir, achei alguns tutoriais que falam em Ajax, mas nenhum deles consegui aplicar. Achei outros que indicavam executar essa função nas views.py, mas também não surgiu resultado.

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer este tipo de aplicação e se sim, como eu poderia fazê-lo? Aceito indicação de tutoriais, exemplos, enfim, qualquer coisa que possa me ajudar.

Comment: Sugiro que retorne a postagem à pergunta e então poste a solução como uma resposta, depois marque-a como resposta aceita. Isso vai ajudar outras pessoas que estejam com um problema similar

Comment: o @Evilmaax tem razão.. Qualquer dúvida leia: [Posso responder minha própria pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Quando a assim edite a pergunta removendo a resposta e adicione a resposta como sendo um wiki.

Answer (score 0):

> **Solução dada pelo autor na própria pergunta.**

Na verdade foi mais simples do que eu pensava. Apenas precisei chamar a função para realizar os processos que ela já faria e depois salvar estes dados no banco de dados. Segue abaixo os arquivos views.py e models.py

```
view.py
def WarmView(request):
if str(request.method) == 'GET':
    image_path = r"C:\Users\bruno\PycharmProjects\teste3\media\termografias"
    for name_file in sorted(os.listdir(image_path)):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_path, name_file))
        temperatura = point.show_warm_point(img, name_file) # Função que executa o processo desejado

        teste_temp = fr"C:\Users\bruno\PycharmProjects\teste3\media\processadas\{name_file}"

        image = Processings()
        image.images = f"{teste_temp}"
        Processings.objects.create(images=image.images, temperature=temperatura)

models.py
class Processings(models.Model):
images = models.ImageField('Processada', upload_to='processadas')
temperature = models.DecimalField('Temperatura', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```